# Determining if a field is using a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I've been baffled by this and can't seem to get my head around it so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a class as follows:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public List<T> Data;
}
```

Now I'm writing code to reflect this class and want to work out a way of determining that the field Data has a generic parameter being used.

My initial approach was to continue going down as many levels as I could and once I hit the IsGenericParameter field set to true I would rather than reflect the type name instead place a "Generic Argument" string there, however I can't seem to get this to work the way I want it to.

I've looked around but every solution I've found seems to point to a dead end with this at the moment.

Comment: What is the initial `System.Type` instance that you have? Is it `typeof(Foo<>)` or something like `typeof(Foo<SomeType>)`?

Comment: Hi @dasblinkenlight the instance is Foo<SomeType>.

Comment: Just to add to this, I then iterate through the fields so when using Foo<SomeType> and I get to the Data field, after the list, the string itself does not have the 'IsGenericParameter' set to true.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to know, that Data uses a generic type ?

Comment: Is `IsGenericType` what you're looking for?  e.g. `typeof(Foo<int>).GetField("Data").FieldType.IsGenericType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to distinguish generic types that rely on class type parameter from generic types that do not. Consider this example:

```
class Foo<T> {
    public List<T> field1;   // You want this field
    public List<int> field2; // not this field
}
```

Start by getting generic type definition, and pulling its type arguments:

```
var g = typeof(Foo<string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
var a = g.GetGenericArguments();
```

This will give you an array with a single type that represents generic type parameter `T`. Now you can go through all fields, and search for that type among generic type arguments of field types, like this:

```
foreach (var f in g.GetFields()) {
    var ft = f.FieldType;
    if (!ft.IsGenericType) continue;
    var da = ft.GetGenericArguments();
    if (da.Any(xt => a.Contains(xt))) {
        Console.WriteLine("Field {0} uses generic type parameter", f.Name);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Field {0} does not use generic type parameter", f.Name);
    }
}
```

This code [produces the following output](http://ideone.com/indUmu):

```
Field field1 uses generic type parameter
Field field2 does not use generic type parameter
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `IsGenericType`, not `IsGenericParameter`:

```
bool isGeneric = typeof(Foo<int>).GetField("Data").FieldType.IsGenericType;
```

If you want to know of the parameter for the `List` is generic, then you have to look one more level down:

```
bool isGeneric = typeof(Foo<>).GetField("Data")
                                 .FieldType
                                 .GetGenericArguments()[0] // only generic argument to List<T>
                                 .IsGenericParameter;
```

> what if `Data` field was a `Dictionary` with `Dictionary<string, T>`. How would I determine which type was using a generic parameter?

Call `GetGenericArguments` on the type and look at each type in the resulting array

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Dictionary<string, T> Bar;
}

Type[] types = typeof(Foo<>).GetField("Bar").FieldType.GetGenericArguments();

Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}",
    types[0].IsGenericParameter,  // false, type is string
    types[1].IsGenericParameter   // true,  type is T
);
```

Basically, `IsGenericParameter` is used when looking at the generic parameters of a type to see if it is generic or if is has a type sepcified.

Comment: Okay, this seems logical, but what if Data field was a Dictionary with Dictionary<string, T>... How would I determine which type was using a generic parameter?

Comment: Thankyou - This too helped me get to the right place but the user above was just ever so slightly quicker so I thought it was fair to mark that as the correct answer :)